# How to represent "class" data type in C or any low level language?

Tags: object-oriented, c, class

I'm writing a simple language compiler,currently it's support functional programming only.

I want to support OOP concept, but I don't know how exactly I can represent an object ? just where to start .

**Edit:**

I just want to how to represent a class data type,not how to inheritance,.. etc.

Comment: Have a look at e.g. "Write you a Haskell" http://dev.stephendiehl.com/fun/

Comment: @pjc50: That's a work in progress.

Comment: http://www.drdobbs.com/object-oriented-programming-in-c/184402190

Comment: There's also a book about this subject "Object Orientated Programming in ANSI-C", in which the author show how object-oriented programming operates at low level and what techniques are used, using ANSI-C .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple objects are just a `struct` containing all the fields.  Methods typically take a pointer to that `struct` as their first argument (like python does).  This simple form of OOP is done all the time in C.

Inheritance makes things more complicated.  You can add a pointer to the parent object from the child object, or include all the parent's fields.  Virtual methods require a vtable as part of the struct, which is basically function pointers for every virtual method.  You need to add code that handles polymorphic dispatch.  Look at [GObject](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/) for a good production-quality example of this kind of OOP in C.

Comment: Thank you,it's really useful answer. Do you know how C++/Java represent objects? or it's like Python does ?

Comment: On a fundamental level, they all look basically the same:  a data structure containing object-specific fields and a vtable.  Any differences are in higher abstraction levels.

Comment: I've looked at the workings of 3 implementations of Java in my time, and they're pretty much exactly as described here. Objects have a pointer to a class descriptor of some kind, which contains a table of pointers to methods. Object Pascal implementations (e.g. Delphi) also follow this pattern. C++ is like this for simple cases, but multiple inheritance makes things get much more complex.